# How to extract a string from text that is 50 chars long and consists of A to Z and 0-9 .. starts with a capital letter

Tags: python, regex

example string

```
 &+^'<>123Abcdiiiiiiiiiiiiii iiiiiiiiiiiii iiii iiiiiii iiii iii iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii iiiiiiiiii iiiiiiiiii iiiiiiiii iiiiii.!'^+%&/()
```

from that string the regex code needs to ask for a string that starts with a capital letter and ends with a dot but is at least 50 characters long and can consist of only 0-9 and A-Z in a case insensitive manner and may also contain double quotes or single quotes as well as dots.

python is the language of choice to test the regex code.

Comment: About your last question(update of my first comment): Because an html document contains several traps for a basic regex (<[^>]*>) that try to avoid html tags. These traps are CDATA, html comments, css, javascript. I don't say you, that it is impossible, but it is not the simplest/cleanest way.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, imagine sleeping for the next 10 years as working on a search engine .. god keeps asking you why you are trying to eliminate html tags.. and you respond.. " i am trying to get the text that is why ".. god responds to you and says.. " then go get the text .. why waste time eliminating html tags ? ".. your face turns red.. god wins..

Comment: Oh, I see. This is probably the theologic reason why you have deleted your previous post.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, the way reality works is everything is connected to logic & rationale. i can not say codes are codes and existence is existence. it's all under one roof .. to some it is known as the big bang theory to some it is known as existence. the same way it makes sense not to resist forces bigger than you in reality.. it makes sense to not resist html tags that are everywhere when working with regex.  logic and rationale remains as logic and rationale even when we step out of the reality and dive into the realms of codes.

Comment: That other answer's code worked better than the chosen answer.. i was about to change the selected answer but they deleted their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reobj = re.compile(r"""(?=[A-Z])([A-Za-z0-9"'. ]{50,}\.)""")
result = reobj.findall(subject)
```

http://regex101.com/r/eH3qP2

Comment: The link was very helpful. ( Allows modifications and downgrades/upgrades )

Answer (score 3):

Im not exactly sure what you are asking, but I assumed you wanted a regex that would grab a string at least 50 chars long, contains only letters and numbers and quotes and ends in a dot.

```
([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9'".]{48,}[.])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This one does not validate that there are numbers in the string. In order to do that you also need a look ahead before you extract the string. This is usually much more advanced and gives you more trouble than its worth. Therefore, it would be better to simply EXTRACT the one above, then VALIDATE it against a second regex

```
(.*[0-9].*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
/^[A-Z][A-z \.'"]{50,}\.$/
```

Comment: **Don't use** `A-z` in a character class, it includes other characters than `[A-Za-z]` (see your nearest ascii table).

Comment: This is wrong `[A-z` it should be `[A-Z`, also, the regex doesn't match the SO example.